# JS/TS syntax: Destructuring assignment with inner assignment

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, syntax

I just stumbled upon [this line of TS code](https://github.com/kenotron/office-ui-fabric-react/blob/b8379cf97a7147d80786053fc7d77a79f24d70d2/packages/office-ui-fabric-react/src/components/Dropdown/Dropdown.base.tsx#L590):

```
const { title = item.text } = item;
```

It seems to be a [destructuring assigment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) but what does the assignment within the curly brackets do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner assignment provides a [default value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

In case `item.title` is undefined `title` will be assign `item.text` instead.

Comment: did you just answer your own question?

Comment: @DevonNorris that's actually an option when asking a question (there is a small checkbox below). It's normally done in cases where OP plan to write a canonical Q/A. It's perfectly fine, *depending* on the Q/A...

Comment: Yes, I found the answer while I was writing the question. And since I was looking quite a while for the answer, I thought I just share it directly with you. @DevonNorris: You might not have enough credit yet to see the mentioned checkbox.